# use Document.Format.OpenXml instead of microsoft.interop.excel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am reading values from an excelsheet and everything works but when I publish on my server it doesn't work anymore. The problem is that I am using microsoft.interop and my server doesn's support that. I think the solution is using Document.Format.OpenXml, I have included the reference but I don't succeed in changing my code the right way. Can someone help me?

My Code:

```
public class ScoreCalculator
 {
    //private static DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Extensions.WorksheetReader appExcell;
    private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application appExcel;
    private static Workbook newWorkbook = null;
    private static Worksheet objsheet = null;

   //Method to initialize opening Excel
   public void excel_init(String path)
   {
      appExcel = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Extensions.WorksheetReader;


          newWorkbook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(path, true, true);
          objsheet = (Worksheet)appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;


  }
```

Comment: That is a _completely_ different (and much nicer) API.  You need to rewrite all of your code.

Comment: Are there good examples on the internet?

Comment: I have no idea.  Google it.

Comment: The good place to start getting familiar with (relativity) new Open XML API is official documentation - [Open XML for Office developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/bb265236.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your server should have Interop assemblies installed for this code to work. Use Open XML sdk 2.5, this generates xlsx format

check this [example](http://blogs.technet.com/b/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/archive/2013/03/04/how-to-use-the-open-xml-sdk-2-0-in-visual-studio-2010-to-create-a-simple-excel-spreadsheet-in-c.aspx)